# Get AdSets by Campaign id

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api

I' using this method for Facebook Markiting API for campaigns. It works perfectly:

```
$account = new AdAccount($account_id);

$campaigns = $account->getCampaigns(array(
        CampaignFields::ID,
        CampaignFields::NAME,
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
        CampaignFields::STATUS,
        CampaignFields::CREATED_TIME,
        CampaignFields::START_TIME,
        CampaignFields::STOP_TIME,
        CampaignFields::UPDATED_TIME,
    )
);
```

Returns Campaign id. I'm trying to get Adsets by Campaign id.
I'm using this code but returns nothing:

```
$adsets = (new AdSet($camp_id))->read(array(
  AdSetFields::NAME,

));


foreach ($adsets as $adset) {
  echo '<br />--<br />';
  echo $adset->{AdSetFields::ID}.PHP_EOL;

  echo '<br />---<br />';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read all ad sets from one ad campaign

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;

$adcampaign = new AdCampaign($adcampaign_id);
$adsets = $adcampaign->getAdSets(array(
  AdSetFields::NAME,
  AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_STATUS
));

// This will output the name of all fetched ad sets.
foreach ($adsets as $adset) {
  echo $adset->name;
}
```

[Ad Campaign](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign)